# What do I keep getting Error: Identifier not found "parish" source.pas(7,9) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but ":" found?

Tags: variables, syntax-error, pascal

```
BEGIN
(*Declaration of variables*)
```

Every time I run my program I keep getting that same error  that something is wrong with the syntax within this section

```
 parish : String; (*Error: identifier not found "parish"*)
 pat_mny, sa_mny, sm_mny, se_mny, sj_mny, p_mny, st_mny : Real; (*Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but ":" found*)
 j, sa, sm, se, sj, p, st, max : Integer;
```

This program computes the total number of patients that visited each parish and displays the maximum parish cost

```
Print ('*****Ministry of Health Database File*****');
Print ('Hello, this is the Dengue Eradication Task Force Computing Program, please make sure to follow the instructions given else there will be a compile error ');
Print('ALL parishes entered MUST BE spelt correctly. Any parish from the parish list may be entered (EXCEPTIONS WILL PRODUCE A COMPILE ERROR).')
Print ('PARISH LIST: St. Ann, St. Mary, St. Thomas, St. Elizabeth, St. James and Portland');




     (*Loop to ensure that the program repeats this block of code 10 times*)
        (*Prompting the user for input*)
    for j :=1-10 do 
        begin
          Write ('Enter the name of the parish the patient visited: ');
        Readln (parish);
        Write ('Enter the amount that the patient paid:');
        Readln (pat_mny);

        (*Processing to compute the number of patients and the total cost for each parish*)
        while (parish := "St. Ann") do

            begin
            sa := 1+0;
            sa_mny := sa_mny+  pat_mny;
            end;

        while (parish := "St. Mary") do 

            begin
            sm:=1+0;
            sm_mny := sm_mny+pat_mny;
            end;

        while (parish := "St. Elizabeth") do

            begin
            se :=1+0;
            se_mny := se_mny+pat_mny;
            end;

        while (parish := "St. Thomas") do

            begin
            st := 1+0;
            st_mny := st_mny+pat_mny;
            end;

        while (parish := "St. James") do

            begin
            sj :=1+0;
            sj_mny := sj_mny+pat_mny;
            end;

        while (parish := "Portland") do

            begin
            p:=1+0;
            p_mny :=p_mny+pat_mny;
            end;

    end;

    (*Processing to compute the maximum cost*)
    max :=0;
    if ( sa<sm) then

        begin
         max:=sm;
        end;

    else if (sm<se) then

        begin
         max:=se; 
        end;

    else if (se<st) then

        begin
         max:=st;
        end;

    else if (st<sj) then

        begin
         max:=sj:
        end;

    else

        begin
         max:=p;
        end;

    end;

    (*Prompting the computer output*)

    Writeln ('St. Ann: Total cost $', sa_mny 'No. of Patients', sa)
    Writeln ('St. Mary: Total cost $', sm_mny 'No. of Patients', sm)
    Writeln ('St. Elizabeth: Total cost $', se_mny 'No. of Patients', se)
    Writeln ('St. Thomas: Total cost $', st_mny `enter code here`'No. of Patients', st)
    Writeln ('St. James: Total cost $', sj_mny 'No. of Patients', sj)
    Writeln ('Portland: Total cost $', p_mny 'No. of Patients', p)
    Writeln ('The maximum total cost is $', max)
    Print ('Thank you for using the DETF Computing Program. Good day!')
    END.
```

Comment: Please format the code at the start of your q (and at the end) the same way you've formatted the rest! Also, which Pascal Compiler ad iDE are you using? FPC + Lazarus or what?

Comment: FPC 3.0.0 online compiler

Comment: This expression is illegal: `while (parish := "St. Ann")`. Assignments in a boolean evaluation is not accepted. Instead, compare against equality and do not use a while loop. Use an `if-then` expression:`if (parish = 'St. Ann') then ...`

Comment: There are lots of errors, the compiler will point you to the line(s) which does not compile. Your variable declaration is wrong for example. It must be written before the `begin` line and stated with a `var` first.

Comment: And variables are declared in a VAR block before BEGIN

Answer (score 0):

This is the correction to the code above...
Thanks to all the persons who took time out to comment on my question to help me. Thanks for your attention.

In the section where I have `Var` at first I had `Begin` and then I declared the variables without using the keyword `var`. I modified the code to correct the syntax error by removing the declaration of variables outside of the code block within the `begin` and `end` section. Also changed `max` to `real` datatype because I wanted it to store a floating point number.

```
Program DETFComputingProgram;
Var
(*Declaration of variables*)

 parish : String; 
 pat_mny, sa_mny, sm_mny, se_mny, sj_mny, p_mny, st_mny, max: Real;
 j, sa, sm, se, sj, p, st : Integer;
```

Earlier I did not initialize my variables. I initialize my variables within the main `begin` and `end`section.

```
Begin
 sa_mny:=0; sm_mny:=0; se_mny:=0; sj_mny:=0; p_mny:=0; st_mny:=0 ;
  sa:=0; sm:=0; se:=0; sj:=0; p:=0; st:=0 ;
```

In this section of code below where I have`Writeln` I had `Print` that caused an error also.

```
Writeln('*****Ministry of Health Database File*****');
Writeln ('Hello, this is the Dengue Eradication Task Force Computing Program, please make sure to follow the instructions given else there will be a compile error ');
Writeln('ALL parishes entered MUST BE spelt correctly. Any parish from the parish list may be entered (EXCEPTIONS WILL PRODUCE A COMPILE ERROR).');
Writeln('PARISH LIST: St. Ann, St. Mary, St. Thomas, St. Elizabeth, St. James and Portland');

(*Loop to ensure that the program repeats this block of code 10 times*)
(*Prompting the user for input*)
```

Earlier I had `for j:=1-10 do`that also gives a syntax error the correct syntax is `for j :=1 to 10 do`. Also I added a semi-colon at the end of one of these lines in the section of code below where it was missing.

```
for j:=1 to 10 do 
begin
  Writeln('Enter the name of the parish the patient visited: ');
Readln (parish);
Writeln('Enter the amount that the patient paid:');
Readln (pat_mny);
```

In this section of code below I had used `while` loop instead of an`if()then`construct. I had `while (parish := "St.Ann") do`. I learnt here that that was an illegal code (thanks) and I took the sugestion to use an `if()then` construct so the code looked like this `if(parish = 'St.Ann') then`.

```
(*Processing to compute the number of patients and the total cost for each parish*)
if (parish ='St. Ann') then
begin
sa := sa+1;
sa_mny := sa_mny+  pat_mny;
end;
if (parish ='St. Mary') then
begin
sm:=sm+1;
sm_mny := sm_mny+pat_mny;
end;
if (parish ='St. Elizabeth')then
begin
se :=se+1;
se_mny := se_mny+pat_mny;
end;
if  (parish = 'St. Thomas') then
begin
st := st+1;
st_mny := st_mny+pat_mny;
end;
if (parish = 'St. James')then
begin
sj :=sj+1;
sj_mny := sj_mny+pat_mny;
end;
if (parish = 'Portland') then
begin
p:=p+1;
p_mny :=p_mny+pat_mny;
end;
end;
```

In this section of code below I had put semicolons at the end of each condition statement example`max:=sm_mny;`. Semi-colons are only supposed to go at the end of statements that come after an `else` in an `if()then` construct. Also I had made some logic errors so I fixed that in order get the correct calculations.

```
(*Processing to compute the maximum cost*)
max :=0;
if ( sa_mny<sm_mny) then
 max:=sm_mny
else 
if (sm_mny<se_mny) then
 max:=se_mny 

else 
if (se_mny<st_mny) then
 max:=st_mny

else 
    if (st_mny<sj_mny) then
     max:=sj_mny
else
 max:=p_mny;
end.
```

(*Prompting the computer output*)

```
Writeln ('St. Ann: Total cost $', sa_mny 'No. of Patients', sa)
Writeln ('St. Mary: Total cost $', sm_mny 'No. of Patients', sm)
Writeln ('St. Elizabeth: Total cost $', se_mny 'No. of Patients', se)
Writeln ('St. Thomas: Total cost $', st_mny 'No. of Patients', st)
Writeln ('St. James: Total cost $', sj_mny 'No. of Patients', sj)
Writeln ('Portland: Total cost $', p_mny 'No. of Patients', p)
Writeln ('The maximum total cost is $', max)
Writeln('Thank you for using the DETF Computing Program. Good day!')
End.
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to appear to yell. Sorry

Comment: Ok thank you for the edits and suggestions. I have made edits to my answer I hope those are suitable explanations.